# Remove all content after last '\' is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to rename a document, I want to remove all the content after the last `'\'` and then give it another name.

I did it like this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
var newDocName = documentPath.replace(/\/$/, '');
var newDocName = newDocName + "\test.pdf";
```

The `'\'` doesn't get removed after the first line of code.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wrong regex. At the moment it searches for a string ending at '/' and then end of string. SO if there's content after the last '/', it won't find anything. You need to change it into\\ for the backslash and then add some quantifiers to check if there's text behind the last \. You might as well just use indexOf the last  slash and slice from there instead of regex.

Comment: How are you reaching your local file system with a browser? `<input type='file'>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/\/$/` means you want to match a `/` if it's the last character in the string meaning this code would replace the very last `/` if, and only if, it's at the end of the string.

If you want to remove the content after the last `\` then you can use a combination of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string on `\`s then use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get everything but the last element. Finally, use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to bring them all back together.

```js
var uri = 'path\\to\\my\\file.ext';
var parts = uri.split('\\');
var withoutFile = parts.slice(0, parts.length - 1);
var putItBackTogether = withoutFile.join('\\');
var voila = putItBackTogether + '\\new-file.name';
console.log(voila);
```

Comment: Only complete answer until now. The other answers forget there's a filename after the last backslash.

Answer (score 1):

It is forward slash, use \\ istead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to substitute it for:

```
var newDocName = documentPath.replace(/\\/$/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your REGEX has a bad format: you should escape your backquotes (`\`).

So it may be:

```
var newDocName = documentPath.replace(/[\\/]$/, '');
var newDocName = newDocName + "\\test.pdf";
```

This regular expression will search for `\` or `/` at the end (`$`) of you path. You could use [regex101](https://regex101.com) to test your regular expressions.

You also should consider **not using regular expressions** when you don’t need them:

```
var newDocName = documentPath[documentPath.length - 1] == "\\" ? documentPath + "test.pdf" : documentPath + "\\test.pdf";
```